# How can I create a default item in my database with Jest so that I could test my API CRUD operations?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I have a complete API build with express that can handle all CRUD operations. My api handles the creation of Services. I'm using an a MYSQL database with my API which contains one table called `service`. Now I want to be able to insert a mock/default **service object** so that I could run that *same* **service object** in all my tests, and delete it at the end so that I don't fill the my service table with redundant data. And I want that **service object** to be put through my almost all my tests except my Post request. How can I accomplish this with Jest?

Here's what I have so far in my service.test.js file

How can I create the service object before all my tests and delete it after all my tests and keep it as a global variable to my file?

Answer (score 1):

Jest provides `beforeAll` and `afterAll` for your problem/situation

- beforeAll - Function will run before all the tests.
- afterAll - Function will run after all the tests

**Code Structure:**

```
...

beforeAll((done) => {
    //Insert your mock data on database
});

afterAll((done) => {
    //Delete your mock data from database 
});

test('', async() => {
   //Your test with database mock data
});

....
```

**Reference :** [Setup and Teardown -> One-Time Setup](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#one-time-setup)